# Ubuntu11.10 to latest upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I've Ubuntu 11.10 in my system. And i want to upgrade it. but the default update manager doesn't show upgrade status. What do I've to do. I've dual boot system with windows 7 in the other. it's a 64 bit system.

Comment: check if all repo are right and then write this command " sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y  && sudo do-release-upgrade " after that follow the steps

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply download the Ubuntu 13.04 ISO, and then proceed like a new install? Just select the option to keep existing files and settings. I feel its much safer than online upgrades..